# Why are these two SWT Composites different in width when they're supposed to be equal?

Tags: button, swt, composite

I am trying to figure out why are the top and bottom composite as seen on the picture have a difference of maybe 1 pixel in width. I am including the the class of the custom composite, and a main method to test it if you want in a seperate class.

[image]

```
public class CustomExpandItem {

  private int _tableCount = 0;

  private int _counter = 1;

  private Composite _newComp;

  private boolean _toBeBold;

  private String _keyWord;

  private Button _button;

  private Composite _styledTextAndButtonComp;

  private Composite _parentComp;

  private ScrolledComposite _scrolledComp;

  private int _styledTextAndButtonCompHeight;

  private Image _buttonImage = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, ObjectLabelConfigDialogConstants.EXPAND_BUTTON_IMAGE_ARROW_LEFT).createImage();

  public CustomExpandItem(Composite parent, String title, boolean toBeBold, String keyWord) {
    _toBeBold = toBeBold;
    _keyWord = keyWord;
    _parentComp = parent;
    _scrolledComp = (ScrolledComposite) parent.getParent();
    Composite item = createItem(parent, title);
  }

  public int getStyledTextAndButtonCompHeight() {
    return _styledTextAndButtonCompHeight;
  }

  public void setStyledTextAndButtonCompHeight(int styledTextAndButtonCompHeight) {
    _styledTextAndButtonCompHeight = styledTextAndButtonCompHeight;
  }

  public Composite getStyledTextAndButtonComp() {
    return _styledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  public int getCounter() {
    return _counter;
  }

  public void setCounter(int counter) {
    _counter = counter;
  }

  public Composite getInnerComp() {
    return _styledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  public Button getButton() {
    return _button;
  }

  public Composite getNewComp() {
    return _newComp;
  }

  protected Composite createItem(Composite parent, String title) {
    _styledTextAndButtonComp = createAndConfigureStyledTextAndButtonComp(parent);
    createAndConfigureStyledTextComp(title, _styledTextAndButtonComp);
    _button = createAndConfigureButton(_styledTextAndButtonComp);
    createAndConfigureNewComp(_styledTextAndButtonComp);
    return _styledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  protected Button createAndConfigureButton(Composite comp) {
    GridData gridDataButton = createGridDataButton();
    _button = createButton(comp, gridDataButton);
    return _button;
  }

  protected Button createButton(Composite comp, GridData gridDataButton) {
    _button = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    _button.setImage(_buttonImage);
    _button.setLayoutData(gridDataButton);
    _button.setBackground(ObjectLabelConfigDialogConstants.GREY_DEFAULT_BUTTON_COLOR);
    _button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        changeExpandedStateOfStyledTextAndButtonComp(comp, _button);
      }

      @Override
      public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      }
    });
    return _button;
  }

  protected void changeExpandedStateOfStyledTextAndButtonComp(Composite styledTextAndButtonComp, Button button) {
    if (_tableCount > 3) {
      GridData newCompWhenExpandedNewGridData = createNewCompGridData(360);
      _newComp.setLayoutData(newCompWhenExpandedNewGridData);
      changeStateOfNewComp(styledTextAndButtonComp, button, 400);
    } else {
      changeStateOfNewComp(styledTextAndButtonComp, button, 250);
    }
    calculateNewSizeOfScrolledComp();
    layoutAll(styledTextAndButtonComp, _newComp);
  }

  protected void calculateNewSizeOfScrolledComp() {
    _scrolledComp.setMinSize(_parentComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    _scrolledComp.layout(true);
  }

  protected void changeStateOfNewComp(Composite styledTextAndButtonComp, Button button, int height) {
    Image buttonImageReversed = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, ObjectLabelConfigDialogConstants.EXPAND_BUTTON_IMAGE_ARROW_DOWN).createImage();
    if (_counter % 2 == 1) {
      showNewComp(styledTextAndButtonComp, height);
      button.setImage(buttonImageReversed);
    } else {
      hideNewComp(styledTextAndButtonComp);
      button.setImage(_buttonImage);
    }
  }

  protected void layoutAll(Composite comp, Composite newComp) {
    comp.getParent().layout();
    comp.layout();
    newComp.layout();
  }

  protected void hideNewComp(Composite comp) {
    _newComp.setVisible(false);
    setNewCompNotExpanded(comp);
    _counter++;
  }

  protected void showNewComp(Composite comp, int height) {
    _newComp.setVisible(true);
    setInnerCompHeight(comp, height);
    _counter++;
  }

  protected void createAndConfigureNewComp(Composite comp) {
    GridData newCompGridData = createNewCompGridData(210);
    _newComp = new Composite(comp, SWT.BORDER);
    _newComp.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    _newComp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    _newComp.setLayoutData(newCompGridData);
    _newComp.setVisible(false);
  }

  protected GridData createNewCompGridData(int height) {
    GridData newCompGridData = new GridData();
    newCompGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    newCompGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    newCompGridData.horizontalSpan = 5;
    newCompGridData.heightHint = height;
    newCompGridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    return newCompGridData;
  }

  protected void setNewCompNotExpanded(Composite comp) {
    GridData newData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    newData.heightHint = 40;
    comp.setLayoutData(newData);
  }

  protected void setInnerCompHeight(Composite comp, int height) {
    GridData newData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    newData.heightHint = height;
    setStyledTextAndButtonCompHeight(height);
    comp.setLayoutData(newData);
  }

  protected GridData createGridDataButton() {
    GridData gridDataButton = new GridData();
    gridDataButton.horizontalSpan = 1;
    gridDataButton.heightHint = 31;
    gridDataButton.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = false;
    gridDataButton.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    return gridDataButton;
  }

  protected void createAndConfigureStyledTextComp(String title, Composite comp) {
    Composite styledTextComp = createStyledTextComp(comp);
    StyledText widget = createStyledText(title, styledTextComp);
  }

  protected Composite createStyledTextComp(Composite comp) {
    Composite styledTextComp = new Composite(comp, SWT.BORDER);
    configureStyledTextComp(comp, styledTextComp);
    return styledTextComp;
  }

  protected void configureStyledTextComp(Composite comp, Composite styledTextComp) {
    styledTextComp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    styledTextComp.setBackground(ObjectLabelConfigDialogConstants.GREY_DEFAULT_BUTTON_COLOR);
    createAndSetGridDatStyledTextComp(styledTextComp);
    styledTextComp.addMouseListener(new MouseLeftClickBehavior(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        changeExpandedStateOfStyledTextAndButtonComp(comp, _button);
      }
    }));
  }

  protected void createAndSetGridDatStyledTextComp(Composite styledTextComp) {
    GridData gridDataStyledTextComp = createGridDataStyledText();
    styledTextComp.setLayoutData(gridDataStyledTextComp);
  }

  protected StyledText createStyledText(String title, Composite comp) {
    StyledText widget = new StyledText(comp, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    configureStyledText(title, comp, widget);
    if (isToBeBold()) {
      boldenStyledText(widget, _keyWord, title);
    }

    return widget;
  }

  protected void configureStyledText(String title, Composite comp, StyledText widget) {
    widget.setText(title);
    widget.setBackground(ObjectLabelConfigDialogConstants.GREY_DEFAULT_BUTTON_COLOR);
    widget.setEditable(false);
    comp.getDisplay();
    Cursor cursor = Display.getCurrent().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_ARROW);
    widget.setCursor(cursor);
    widget.addMouseListener(new MouseLeftClickBehavior(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        changeExpandedStateOfStyledTextAndButtonComp(comp.getParent(), _button);
      }
    }));
  }

  protected Composite createAndConfigureStyledTextAndButtonComp(Composite parent) {
    GridLayout gridLayoutInnerComposite = createGridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp();
    GridData gridDataInnerComposite = createGridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp();
    Composite innerComp = createStyledTextAndButtonComp(parent, gridLayoutInnerComposite, gridDataInnerComposite);
    return innerComp;
  }

  protected GridData createGridDataStyledText() {
    GridData gridDataStyledText = new GridData();
    gridDataStyledText.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridDataStyledText.horizontalSpan = 4;
    gridDataStyledText.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    gridDataStyledText.heightHint = 25;
    return gridDataStyledText;
  }

  protected Composite createStyledTextAndButtonComp(Composite parent, GridLayout gridLayoutInnerComposite, GridData gridDataInnerComposite) {
    Composite styledTextAndButtonComp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    //TODO (shristov): REMOVE!
    System.out.println("StyledTextAndButtonComp Size: " + styledTextAndButtonComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    styledTextAndButtonComp.setLayout(gridLayoutInnerComposite);
    styledTextAndButtonComp.setLayoutData(gridDataInnerComposite);
    styledTextAndButtonComp.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    return styledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  protected GridData createGridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp() {
    GridData gridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    gridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp.heightHint = 40;
    gridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    return gridDataStyledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  protected GridLayout createGridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp() {
    GridLayout gridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp = new GridLayout();
    gridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp.numColumns = 5;
    gridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    gridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp.verticalSpacing = 0;
    return gridLayoutStyledTextAndButtonComp;
  }

  protected void boldenStyledText(StyledText widget, String keyWord, String text) {
    String textToLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();
    String[] splitted = textToLowerCase.split("\\s+"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    for (String word : splitted) {
      if (word.contains(keyWord.toLowerCase())) {
        int index = textToLowerCase.indexOf(word);
        int offset = word.indexOf(keyWord.toLowerCase());
        if (index != -1) {
          StyleRange range = new StyleRange(index + offset, keyWord.length(), null, null, SWT.BOLD);
          widget.setStyleRange(range);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected boolean isToBeBold() {
    return _toBeBold;
  }

  protected int getTableCount() {
    return _tableCount;
  }

  protected void setTableCount(int tableCount) {
    _tableCount = tableCount;
  }

}
```

Test class with main method:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class CustomExpandItemDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    Display display = shell.getDisplay();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    //create outerComp
    GridLayout gridLayoutOuterComp = new GridLayout();
    gridLayoutOuterComp.numColumns = 1;

    ScrolledComposite shellComp = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    shellComp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Composite outerComp = new Composite(shellComp, SWT.NONE);
    outerComp.setLayout(gridLayoutOuterComp);

    String testText = "Composite 1";
    CustomExpandItem item = new CustomExpandItem(outerComp, testText, true, "comp");
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    Composite tableArea = new Composite(item.getNewComp(), SWT.NONE);
    tableArea.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    tableArea.setLayoutData(gridData);
    tableArea.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

    String testText1 = "Composite 2";
    CustomExpandItem item1 = new CustomExpandItem(outerComp, testText1, false, "comp");

    String testText2 = "Composite 3";
    CustomExpandItem item2 = new CustomExpandItem(outerComp, testText2, false, "comp");

    shellComp.setContent(outerComp);
    shellComp.setMinSize(outerComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    shellComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    shellComp.setExpandVertical(true);

    tableArea.layout();
    outerComp.layout();
    shellComp.layout(true);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Show us a proper [mre], all these things interact and it is hard to make out exactly what is happening from snippets of code

Comment: @greg-449 I have edited my code. I hope it's easier to understand my issue now. Tell me if there's something not good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That still doesn't come close to being an [mre]. Copying that and pasting it in to test code show references to various missing fields and classes.

Comment: @greg-449 I have included now the two classes you need to test it out.

Comment: There is still way too much code here, and it looks like it expects a ScrolledComposite parent or something. As far as I can see you are expecting a button control to extend to the very edge of the composite to match the border of another composit.e There is no guarantee of that, in fact on my macOS system a button looks very different and doesn't come anywhere near the edge.